# variable mutation from numeric to character according to a condition

Tags: r

In my data frame I have a numeric column `var1`. In that column, all the values that are 30 or less, I want to have as "<=30" and the variable type should be character.

This code sure recognizes values less than 30, and that results either TRUE or FALSE.

```
Mydata <- Mydata %>% select(
    "var1") %>%
  mutate(less_than_30 = (var1 <= 30))
```

With this clumsy code I tried to transform TRUE's into "<=30", but that doesn't work because `! Can't convert <character> to <logical>.`, though I think it should read `<logical> to <character>`

```
Mydata["less_than_30"][Mydata["less_than_30"] == "TRUE"] <- "<=30"
```

I'm sure there is a handy way to do this. Can you help?

Comment: `mutate(less_than_30 = if_else(var1 <= 30, "<=30", paste(var1))`. A column in a data frame must be all one data type, so we can accomplish this by making both options character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```r
Mydata <- Mydata %>% select(
    "var1") %>%
  mutate(less_than_30 = ifelse(var1 <= 30,'<=30',NA))
```